# understanding the conversion in summations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to understand the below conversion. How 10 came in the first term (highlighted bold) in the result equation from the first one in the first term, there is no b in the first term and hence first summation must not have any effect ?

$$\sum_{a=1}^9 \sum_{b=0}^9 (101a + 10b)=\sum_{a=1}^9\left[10(101a)+10 \sum_{b=0}^9  b\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works roughly like this (for finite or absolutely convergent sums):
$$\sum\sum(X+Y) = \sum\sum X +\sum\sum Y$$
$$\sum_a\sum_b X =\sum_b\sum_aX$$
And if $X$ is independent of $a$ then $$\sum_{a=i}^n X= (n-i+1)X,$$
so long as $i\le n.$

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite it with parentheses,
\begin{align}
\sum_{a=1}^9\biggl(\,\sum_{b=0}^9 (101a + 10b)\biggr)
&=\sum_{a=1}^9\biggl(\,\sum_{b=0}^9 101a + \sum_{b=0}^9 10b\biggr)\\[6px]
&=\sum_{a=1}^9\biggl(10\cdot101a +  \sum_{b=0}^9 10b\biggr)\\[6px]
&=\sum_{a=1}^9 10\cdot101a + \sum_{a=1}^9 \biggl(\,\sum_{b=0}^9 10b\biggr)\\[6px]
&=\sum_{a=1}^9 10\cdot101a + \sum_{b=0}^9 \biggl(\,\sum_{a=1}^9 10b\biggr)\\[6px]
&=\sum_{a=1}^9 10\cdot101a + \sum_{b=0}^9 9\cdot 10b\\[6px]
\end{align}

The key is that
$$
\sum_{b=0}^9 x = 10x
$$
(where $x$ doesn't depend on $b$) because you're simply specifying ten equal summands. More generally, for $m\le n$,
$$
\sum_{b=m}^n x=(m-n+1)x
$$